# graphQL, find/filter nodes that have a specific field

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Suppose you have this query

```
{
  "data": {
    "allSitePage": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "context": {
              "frontmatter": null
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "context": {
              "frontmatter": null
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "context": {
              "frontmatter": {
                "date": "2019.02.14",
              }
            }
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can you filter **by the existence** of `date`? 
Something like

```
{
  allSitePage(filter: {context: {frontmatter: {title: true } } } ) {
    edges {
      node {
        context {
          frontmatter {
            date
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

EDITED

This works

`(filter: {context: {frontmatter: {title: {ne:null }}}})`

but is this the best way?

Comment: GraphQL doesn't have any native notion of "filter".  Is this question more specific to some schema or framework?

Comment: It also may help to ask the question "is `frontmatter` not `null`" rather than "is `date` present": in GraphQL you will always get back every field you request on objects that exist.

Comment: the framework is gatsby, and I get your point with your 2nd comment, which is what I've done at the end